# Google APIs credentials - Authorized redirect URIs

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

My god. need help on this. Can anybody tell me why is that Google does not allow public IP address for 'Authorized redirect URIs'?

"Cannot be a public IP address"

[image: Google APIs Form]

Answer (score 0):

You can give your project url for authorization url.